# jQuery: Bootstrap Modal not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to my grant my Admin the priviledges to add and edit user. Clicking the `Add` button pops up a modal which os `userModal` and its working perfectly - I send a request to  `user_action.php` (where my PHP and SQL statements are) and it creates a new user.

When the Admin clicks on the `Update` button, i want the `userModal` to pop up again, but this time, populated with the `username`, `email` and `usertype` of the user that is to be edited (The `modal-title` changes from `Add User` to `Edit User` and the `btn-action` changes to 'Edit`). This is not working - the modal doesn't show.

What is the problem?

I have attached the html to my `users.php` and the jQuery. I have also attached the screenshot of the UI of `users.php` in case it can be of help.

HTML

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include("./database/dbnew.php");

if($_SESSION['usertype'] != 'Admin')
{
 header("location:index.php");
}

include("./templates/header.php");
?>

<span id="alert_action"></span>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">User List</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" align="right">
                                <button type="button" name="add" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="clear:both"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
                            <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Email</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Edit</th>
                                        <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="userModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" id="user_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter User Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter User Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usertype">Usertype</label>
                            <select name="usertype" class="form-control" name="usertype" id="usertype" required>
                            <option value="">Choose User Type</option>
                            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                            <small id="t_error" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                        <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add_button').click(function(){
        $('#user_form')[0].reset();
        $('.modal-title').html("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add User");
        $('#action').val("Add");
        $('#btn_action').val("Add");
    });

    var userdataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [],
        "ajax":{
            url:"user_fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        },
        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "target":[4,5],
                "orderable":false
            }
        ],
        "pageLength": 25
    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#action').attr('disabled','disabled');
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:"user_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
                $('#action').attr('disabled', false);
                userdataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");//user_id
        var btn_action = 'fetch_single';
        $.ajax({
            url:"user_action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id, btn_action:btn_action},//user_id
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#userModal').modal('show');
                $('#username').val(data.username);
                $('#email').val(data.email);
                $('#usertype').val(data.usertype);
                $('.modal-title').html("<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> Edit User");
                $('#id').val(id);//user_id
                $('#action').val('Edit');
                $('#btn_action').val('Edit');
                $('#password').attr('required', false);
                $('#usertype').attr('required', false);
                
            }
        })
    });

});
</script>
```

Screenshot

[users.php UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWrLI.png)

Any form of assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: The php tag needs a whitespace after the word php. It must be <?php here code. Not <?phphere code.

Comment: Yeah @IgorGreg it happened because i didn't insert the screenshot correctly. Thanks, i had fixed that already.

Comment: Any error in console when you click an an `.update` button? And did you confim the `success` callback is fired?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette there's no error in console when i click the `.update` button. Please i'm really new to this and i don't know how to confirm `success` callback. Can you help me out? Is there an alternate way to achieve all this?

Comment: To make sure the success callback is executing, add a `console.log("Callback!!")` inside of it... Right above `$('#userModal').modal('show');`. Another debugging thing I would do is `console.log($('#userModal').lenght)` which should print `1`. -- I see that you correctly use `$('#userModal').modal('show');` and `$('#userModal').modal('hide');`... But did you use `$('#userModal').toggle();` somewhere? it is something I've seen in the past that was making a modal show not working...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I added `console.log("Callback!!");` and it didn't print anything on the console. Also, i added `console.log($('#userModal').length);` above my `ajax` request and it printed `1`. Also i didn't use `$('#userModal').toggle();` anywhere. Now that `console.log($('#userModal').length);` printed `1`, please what do i do?